# Promise.all() after Promise.then() returning undefined values

Tags: javascript, promise

I have the following code

```
var pOne = new Promise(function(callback){
    setTimeout(function(){
        callback(false);
    }, 100);
}).then(function(v){
    console.log("pOne: " + v);
});

var pTwo = new Promise(function(callback){
    setTimeout(function(){
        callback(true);
    }, 100);
}).then(function(v){
    console.log("pTwo: " + v);
});

Promise.all([pOne, pTwo]).then(function(values){
    console.log(values);
});
```

The `console.log(values)` displays `[undefined, undefined]` in the console. My understanding of promises is that I should be able to chain the `then()` method. Does chaining not work with the `Promise.all()` or is this a bug.

Note: I am using the [promise-polyfill](https://github.com/taylorhakes/promise-polyfill) but running it on chrome, so it technically it is using native chrome implementation of promises.

Comment: Your chaining is working fine. The function you're passing into `then` is returning nothing (equivalent to `undefined`), so that's what you're getting. If you want to pass along the values you need to do so explicitly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your pOne and pTwo promises don't return anything.

Try this:

```
var pOne = new Promise(function(callback){
    setTimeout(callback, 100, true);
}).then(function(v){
    return v;
});

var pTwo = new Promise(function(callback){
    setTimeout(callback, 100, false);
}).then(function(v){
    return v;
});

Promise.all([pOne, pTwo]).then(function(values){
    console.log(values);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

`pOne` and `pTwo` have to **resolve** with a value in order for that value to be passed to the result of `Promise.all`.

```
var pOne = new Promise(function(callback){
    setTimeout(function(){
        callback(false);
    }, 100);
}).then(function(v){
    console.log("pOne: " + v);
    return v;
});
```

Notice the `return v` inside of the `.then` callback. That means that the `pOne` promise is going to **resolve** with that value (`v` in this case being whatever the previous Promise resolved with, or in this case, `false`.

Now do the same for the `pTwo` promise.

```
var pTwo = new Promise(function(callback){
    setTimeout(function(){
        callback(true);
    }, 100);
}).then(function(v){
    console.log("pTwo: " + v);
    return v;
});
```

Again, we have to return a value from the `.then` callback function in order for the Promise to resolve with a value, rather than with undefined.

Now, `Promise.all` is going to run the Promises, and when (or if) they resolve (in our case they always do), it's going to get the **resolved** value from each one, and the `Promise.all` promise itself is going to **resolve** with the values.